# How do I turn an unreal engine build file into an msix?

Tags: visual-studio, exe, unreal-engine4, msix

I have developed a simple game with unreal engine 4.22.2. I have a built file with an exe that I would like to turn into an msix file for publishing to the Microsoft store. I know how to do this once the exe is built as an app in visual studio, but when I take the exe out of the built file, it ceases to function, so it isn’t a desktop app that stands alone. Can anybody tell me how to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Here's a guide: https://github.com/kasp1/dozer-pipelines/tree/main/sample-pipelines/microsoft-store

You can pick any commands from the guide/pipeline that you may find useful.